# Selecting GTK Treeview item from Code

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, gtk, gtk#

After i add some items to the GTK Tree View,i need to select the first item in the list from code to fire the treeviewcursorchanged event ie:when clicking on a tree view item.I need to select the first treeview item.But there is no select event.
I populate the treeview with strings

```
    liststore = new ListStore (typeof(string));
    treeview1.Model = liststore;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `Gtk.TreeSelection` associated to the `Gtk.TreeView`. To select the first row just do as follows:

```
Gtk.TreeIter iter;
if (liststore.GetIterFirst(out iter))
    treeview1.Selection.SelectIter(iter);
```

Here is a complete example that creates a list view/model, adds a signal handler to the selection changed event and then sets the first row as selected:

```
var view = new Gtk.TreeView();
var cell = new Gtk.CellRendererText();
var col1 = new Gtk.TreeViewColumn();
col1.Title = "Column 1"
col1.PackStart(cell, true);
col1.AddAttribute(cell, "text", 0);

view.AppendColumn(col1);

var model = new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string));
model.AppendValues("AAA");
model.AppendValues("BBB");
model.AppendValues("CCC");

view.Model = model;

// This is the selection changed handler: I use a lambda but
// it is as easy to use a delegate `Changed` is a standard C#
// event.
view.Selection.Changed += (sender, e) => {
    Console.WriteLine("SELECTION WAS CHANGED");
    Gtk.TreeIter selected;
    if (view.Selection.GetSelected(out selected)) {
        Console.WriteLine("SELECTED ITEM: {0}", model.GetValue(selected, 0)));
    }
};

Gtk.TreeIter iter;
if (model.GetIterFirst(out iter))
     view.Selection.SelectIter(iter);
```

Comment: Thanks,it selected the first item but the cursor changed event was not fired.Im using  this event to run code when an item is selected.Isnt this the right event?

Comment: Have you tried using the Gtk.TreeView.Selection.SelectionChanged event?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,was busy with some other stuff.There is no such event please see http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TreeView

Comment: The event is on the Selection not on the TreeView ;)

Comment: can you tell me how to get the index of the selected row?

Comment: Now I am away from the computer but later I'll add a full example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks,there was no notification,so did not check :)

Comment: what i did was,i added  treeview1.Selection.Changed+= (object sender, EventArgs e) => treeviewselected(); and created the required method.From another method that is not associated with the treeview selection changed i need to get the index of the current treeview selection.I also have liststore = new ListStore (typeof(string));
  treeview1.Model = liststore;

Answer (score 1):

The logic for selections in a `GtkTreeView` are separated into its own class, [`GtkTreeSelection`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeSelection.html). Each `GtkTreeView` has its own `GtkTreeSelection`, obtainable with `gtk_tree_view_get_selection()`.

Once you have the `GtkTreeSelection`, all you need to do is obtain a `GtkTreeIter` to the row you want to select and call `gtk_tree_selection_select_iter()`. You can also build a `GtkTreePath` and select that with `gtk_tree_selection_select_path()`.

How you obtain the `GtkTreeIter` or `GtkTreePath` is up to you. [These are the methods that apply to `GtkTreePath`s and `GtkTreeModel`s.](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html) A `GtkListStore` is also a `GtkTreeModel`, and [has its own methods](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.But was looking for something specific in c#

Comment: It's the same in any language. You will need to find the correct method names for your binding set (they'll probably be something like `select_iter()` or so) and there might be various `ref`s and `out`s sprinkled about. The [`Gtk.TreeSelection`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TreeSelection), [`Gtk.TreeModel`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TreeModel), and [`Gtk.TreePath`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.TreePath) pages on the Mono documentation website should help... if those are the right version of GTK+.